# Azure Point 2 Site: IKEv2 VPN for Windows

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) it is stated:

> IKEv2 VPN, a standards-based IPsec VPN solution. IKEv2 VPN can be used
> to connect from Mac devices (macOS versions 10.11 and above).

For me, that means that IKEv2 is only possible for Mac Clients

However, we are using Windows Clients to connect via IKEv2. Here, a screenshot from my settings:

[image]

Is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/work-remotely-support#p2s) IKEv2 is supported on Windows via its native client. I think the document you shared is missing some information, I will create a documentation feedback item for this.

[image]